# Which technology is better extjs or dojo?

Tags: extjs, dojo

I want to implement Grid which loads a very huge amount of data, performing search in grid contents, pagination. The data to grid from serverside.And I want to add rows to grid, delete rows and update the inserted rows in database. I want to know which is better technology to implement grid with the above requirements. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816925/jquery-vs-dojo-vs-extjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both projects are great. Actually dojo is greater than Extjs. But Ext JS is a relatively young framework (compared to dojo). DOJO grid loads data quicker and allows filtering and sorting of the whole dataset.

However Dojo had several attempts in pushing for some good looking themes. Unfortunately they did not get that “good looking widgets” and “pixel-perfect” layout. Widgets are still difficult to integrate.

Refer to this [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136114-Grid-Performance-and-Paging-issues) for more opinions

Answer (score 8):

Adventages of ExtJs 4.2.1.883 Over Dojo 1.9.2

- Better Documentation
- Grid has row Grouping
- Grid has rowGrouping + selectionModel (checkbox for selecting single, simple, or multiple rows) Together
- Grid has rowEditor (Editing all elements of the row at once) and Dojo only has cell editing (one cell by time). This is useful if you want to pre-validate row data before send the row record to the server
- Grid has row Summary
- <s>They use SASS instead pure CSS</s>
- Programming only in JavaScript (you only need index.html everything else is javascript)
- Stable MVC (in Dojo you need to use Dojox/MVC which is not 100% stable)
- DOM is rendered only one time, only after all JS has finished loading, while Dojo renders twice the same element (First during loading the page and them after dojo has created or modified widgets)

Disaventages of ExtJs Over Dojo

- ExtJs is non-free for commercial ussage

For more exact comparison you can see this link:

http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/#featurecomparison

Althouth it only shows you dGrid vs ExtJs Grid, this could be an starting point. Furthermore, most of my development time is spent in the Grid, so the grid is the most important element in a Business application.

---

Note: Dojo use LESS for all it's bundled styles and Stylus for Bootstrap Style